# How to show time (Hour and minute) and add the time for 30 minute

Tags: c#

I have a project about borrowing bicycle app. This is my first project and i dont know how to show time and how to add 30minute in it

My algorithm is like this
-the costumer borrow the bicycle
-display time when the costumer borrow the bicycle
-display time when the costumer have to return the bicycle(30 minute after borrowing)
-the total price is 3USD for 30 minute(1USD per ten minute)
-display the total price

So, how can i display the time he borrow the bicycle, time when he have to return it(30mnt) and thw total price

Comment: C# has the concept of a `DateTime`. That can represent a point in time. For example it's 10:35pm on 16-dec-2021 US Central time, and a DateTime can hold that information. There's also a `TimeSpan` which represents the difference between two times. If you subtract two DateTimes, you get a TimeSpan. Both types can be formatted in several standard fashions (in a custom format). Your solution should be able to be built from those parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show time you can use DateTime wich is a struct so you don´t need to make an instance of it.
to get the current time: DateTime.Now;
to add 30 minutes to that time DateTime.AddMinutes(30);
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I see, thanks bro this is work